# Symfony2 Query with complex SQL in Repository

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Bit of background first: we have a well evolved solution using Symfony1 and Propel which need to be migrated forward in time so I'm investigating migrating it to Symfony2.8 (with Doctrine).

I've not found a solution yet to having some SQL running it and then "hydrating" the results to object(s).

Any ideas.
Essentially I want to be able to do

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$conn = $em->getConnection();

$sql = "SELECT xxxx";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(1, $siteId);   
$rs = $stmt->execute();
$icount=0;
while ($rs->getnext())
{
   $entity[$icount] = new Entity();
   $entity[$icount] = hydrate($rs);
   $icount++;        
}
```

(those knowing propel will recognise this)
And I do get that if there is more than one entity in the query this should be in a service class of some kind.

Answer (score 0):

I'd look into native SQL queries in doctrine. You can run regular SQL queries and get them hydrated into doctrine objects, with a little extra work.

[Documentation here](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html)